# accessing your usb devices inside docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, mount

Ubuntu 18.04

do you think with mounting /dev host folder on docker container, I can access ttys inside container ?

thanks

Comment: As a general rule, if you need to access host hardware devices, an isolation system like Docker is the wrong tool.  Run your program directly on the host.

Comment: I can't! that is why I am using docker!!

Comment: Which host platform do you have ?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is my host

Comment: There is a `--device` flag for `docker run` expressly to expose host devices to your container. If you run your container in privileged mode it will have access to all devices.